# Wait for ajax to complete before method return

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I know I can set the call to synchronous, or wrap everything preceeding in the complete() callback, but it seems inelegant. Here's what i've got:

```
_loadShader: (url) ->   
    (@_loadResource url, false).complete (e) ->
        vert = e.responseText.split '[Vertex shader]'
        frag = vert[1].split '[Fragment shader]'

        vertex: frag[0]
        fragment: frag[1]

_loadResource: (url, async) ->
    url = 'Public/' + url

    $.ajax
        url: url
        dataType: 'text'
        async: async or true
        complete:
            @
```

_loadShader() returns the XHR object, but what I really want is for it to not return until complete() gets fired - even if that means locking the browser. What I do with the result is important, and I don't want to start wrapping my code up in callbacks.

edit: re-jigged to this, does precisely what I was after:

```
_loadShader: (url, e) ->    
    result = @_loadResource url, false
    vert = result.split '[Vertex shader]'
    frag = vert[1].split '[Fragment shader]'

    shader = 
        vertex: frag[0]
        fragment: frag[1]

_loadResource: (url, async = true) ->
    url = 'Public/' + url
    xhr = $.ajax
        url: url
        dataType: 'text'
        async: async
    return xhr.responseText
```

Comment: So you want a synchronous Ajax call, but don't want to set `async` to false?

Comment: No, i'm fine with setting it to false, but I can't prevent _loadShader() from returning - should i be sticking it in a while loop or something?

Comment: Won't `async or true` always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: Good point - but changed it and the method is still returning before the ajax result is received.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, but I don't know enough CoffeeScript to say why it's happening like that. With `async` false, if it's not cross-domain or JSON-P, it waits.

Comment: You should change it to `async ? true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is

1. You call `$.ajax` with `async: false`
2. The server responds, and jQuery runs any callbacks you've passed to `$.ajax`
3. The `_loadResource` function returns. You then attach a `complete` callback to the XHR object it returned. But because all XHR callbacks were already run, this has no effect.

You should, instead, pass in your `complete` callback as an argument to `_loadResource`, and have it provide that callback to `$.ajax`. So the call becomes

```
@_loadResource url, false, (e) -> ...
```

and the function definition becomes

```
_loadResource: (url, async = true, complete = (->)) ->
  $.ajax {url, dataType: 'text', async, complete}
```

Comment: How do I then do something similar for the caller? ie. @_loadShader shouldnt return until result received. I was hoping to wrap/hide the callback shenanigans in these functions so that the function itself only returns once the result is received.

Answer (score 0):

I never found better solution, than setting private variable to function and then setting that variable to data in jquery callback.

Code would look like this:

```
_loadResource: (url) ->
    resource = null #will cause resource to be private variable of _loadResource, not of callback.
    $.ajax
        url: url
        async: false
        success: (data) ->
            resource = data #setting resource to what jquery got from server.
    resource #returning resource.
```

It compiles to:

```
_loadResource: function(url) {
  var resource;
  resource = null;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      return resource = data;
    }
  });
  return resource;
}
```